# Failed to Install unstructured[pdf] in python:3.11-alpine docker image

Tags: python, numpy, dockerfile, alpine-linux, python-3.11

I tried to install unstructured[pdf] in python:3.11-alpine docker image for our langchain LLM operation. Throughout the process, I also installed those dependencies apk where internally unstructured[pdf] tried to install opencv-python and due to pip backtracking runtime it will "looking at multiple versions of setuptools to determine which version is compatible with other requirements." and will hit into some version conflict issue of numpy as show in below snippet log"

[image: 1]

Anyone try the installation on unstructured[pdf] before in python 3.11 alpine?

Tried install unstructured[pdf] and compile the docker image but failed.. IF someone tried before can share me the solution or steps to install that